# Extjs Tool tip for chart category label

Tags: extjs, charts, tooltip

Here is the Label object

```
,
                                label: {
                                    rotate: {
                                        degrees: 90
                                    },
                                    renderer: function(v){
                                     var toolTip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                                     target: this,
                                     html: v,
                                     anchor: 'left',
                                     dismissDelay: 0,
                                     showDelay: 0,
                                     autoHide: false
                                 });

                                                     toolTip.on('show', function(){

                                                         var timeout;

                                                         toolTip.getEl().on('mouseout', function(){
                                                             timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
                                                                 toolTip.hide();
                                                             }, 500);
                                                         });

                                                         toolTip.getEl().on('mouseover', function(){
                                                             window.clearTimeout(timeout);
                                                         });

                                                         Ext.get(targetId).on('mouseout', function(){
                                                             timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
                                                                 toolTip.hide();
                                                             }, 500);
                                                         });

                                                     });




                                     if(v.length>10)
                                         return Ext.util.Format.substr(v,0,10) +'...' ;  
                                 }
                                }
```

This code is not not creating the tool tip. No error occurs. Is there any other method to create the category label tool tip.
Thanks,
Anish

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? And what is not working ?